# Ubuntu 19.04 cannot connect to TV with HDMI

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, 19.04

I have an HP Pavilion with full hd but when I connect my HDMI cable, is not read nor recognized. I have a nvidia graphic card (driver 430)

This is my xranrd output:

```
  xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

Output from xrandr --verbose:

```
    xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x2ac) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x2ab
    Timestamp:  28051
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1920x1080 (0x2ac) 159.667MHz *current
        h: width  1920 start    0 end    0 total 1920 skew    0 clock  83.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start    0 end    0 total 1080           clock  77.00Hz
```

Output from lspci:

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e10 (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port (rev f0)
00:1d.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try taking away your gpu and connect the screen to your motherboard's default vga to see if it comes from the screen.

Comment: I should have said that I am not expert and I am very good at coping and paste codes in my terminal, but not much else. No idea how to take out the gpu

Comment: is it a laptop or a desktop, if a desktop just unplug it and open the lid, you'll recognize your graphic card because it's big and has a fan, also it should be written nvidia on it. There are mechanism for taking it out without forcing it.

Comment: It's a laptop. I am not really confortable in open it. The problem could be related with 19.04? Would this improve if I install 16 or 18?

Comment: Ok don't open it the gpu is welded inside. Did you install the driver ? Open bash by pressing alt+ctrl+t and type in `sudo apt install nvidia-346`. Maybe it will sort things out as maybe you have 340 installed (i'm guessing you misstyped version number)

Comment: In software and updates was written that the recommended card was 430. Do you think that 346 would work better? How do I find out which driver is the optimal one? I also have problems when watching 1080p video (video tearing and black color showing badly)

Comment: I had issues with my nvidia 1050GTX.
First I had installed the latest driver (for me it was 392)
Then I installed the 340 and it did not work at all.
Lastly I installed the 346 and it installed the latest drivers automatically BUT it also seems to install more file and it works fine. I don't know what really happened. Try it (in a terminal `sudo apt install nvidia-346`)

Comment: As I messed up everything I installed ubuntu 14 and I've upgraded until the 18 (don't want to install 19 because that might have been the problem). I am currently using 390 and I can see HDMI! I don't know if the reason is using 18 or using driver 390 but I will it a win and keep it like these! :) Still it did not fix my other problem, I still see the hd video with lines in the middle. If you know something about that I have another question going on! Thank you for your help!